# Backtracking in a recursive maze; python

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, maze, recursive-backtracking

I'm coding a maze solving algorithm and I'm having trouble with the backtracking once you hit a "wall"

So far I have that my code checks some basic recursive cases such as if I've reached the end or if I have checked all points. I've also made it so that there's a list that keeps track of the solution "path" and adds and removes points accordingly. So every time it adds a point, it checks if its valid and checks the point, above, to the left, to the right, and below etc. If none are valid then this statement is executed

```
    else:
    path.pop()
    return solve_maze(maze,path,end)
```

this removes the point and backtracks and checks the following conditions at the beginning of the function.

```
square = list(path[-1])

#Base Case

if end in path:
    return True

elif square == None:
    return False

elif maze[square[0]][square[1]] == "X":
    path.pop()
    return solve_maze(maze,path,end)

elif tuple(square) in path:
    path.pop()
    return solve_maze(maze,path,end)
```

However when I execute the last line, it just removes all the points in my path and i get an indexing error.

Any advice on how I can backtrack once I hit a dead end?

Comment: If you want to escape a maze you just need to choose a wall and follow it, you do not need recursion

Comment: the way were asked to do it is with recursion; once you hit a wall you must backtrack

Comment: can you provide the entire function, an example of input/output, and where your solution is failing? It is basically very difficult to help you with the details that you gave us

Comment: The common (googlable) name for this procedure is depth-first search.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a heavily commented solution:

```
def backtrack(i,j):
   # if matrix[i][j] is visited, then do nothing
   # if it is a wall, then do not insert it in the path from the first place
   if visit[i][j] != 0 or matrix[i][j] == 'X':
      return
   # mark the index as visited as to not visit it again
   visit[i][j] = 1
   # add the index to the path
   path.append((i,j))
   # if it is the GOAL, then store this path somewhere, 
   # and pop the last index to traverse other paths that reaches the GOAL
   if matrix[i][j] == 'G':
      # any paths that reach the GOAL are appended here
      ans.append(list(path))
      path.pop()
      return
   # loop on the neighbors. if they are valid indices, do the same work again
   for k in range(3):
      nwi = i + row[k]
      nwj = j + col[k]
      if valid(nwi, nwj):
         backtrack(nwi, nwj)
   # after finishing this index, just pop because we do not need it any more
   path.pop()
   return

def valid(i,j):
   return (i >= 0 and i <=2) and (j >= 0 and j <= 2)

# just a dummy matrix to start with
matrix = [['.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'X', '.'], ['.', 'G', 'X']]
# an array that marks indices as visited or not
visit = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
# the path that is used in the back tracking
path = []
# this will be a list of lists containing ALL the paths that can reach the GOAL
ans = []
# these are the neighbors indices
row = [-1, 1, 0, 0]
col = [0, 0, 1, -1]

backtrack(0,0)

if len(ans) == 0: 
   print("no path found!")
else:
   print(ans)
```

My solution will give you all the paths that can reach your target in a list of lists called ***ans***. If the length of ***ans*** is zero, then no paths are found.

If you didn't understand the comments written in the code or are by any means confused, do not hesitate at all to comment down and I will reply.

***NOTE:***(edit)

> I assumed the starting states of the maze and the function content itself because you didn't provide any test cases or your full function itself.